# Unable to pass data form SecurityAttribute class to controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using mvc 3 code first. facing problem while passing data form SecurityAttribute class to Controller. i actually want to redirect user on login page with displaying Message. for this i override AuthorizeCore method in SecurityAttribute class. in this method i am unable to direct use session, cookies, tempdate, and viewbag etc. any other solution to solve this problem. Thanks

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["UserID"] == null)
        {
            //here i am unable to pass message to User/LogOn action.
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/User/LogOn");
           // httpContext.Session["lblMsg"] = "You are not authroize to perform this                               action.Please Login through different account";
            return false; 
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, you should not redirect inside the `AuthorizeCore` method. You should use the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method which is intended for this purpose. As far as passing an error message to the LogOn action is concerned you could use TempData:

```
public class SecurityAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // perform the custom authorization logic here and return true or false
        // DO NOT redirect here
        return httpContext.Session["UserID"] != null;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "You are not authroize to perform this action.Please Login through different account";

        // calling the base method will actually throw a 401 error that the
        // forms authentication module will intercept and automatically redirect
        // you to the LogOn page that was defined in web.config
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then inside the LogOn action:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    string errorMessage = TempData["ErrorMessage"] as string;
    ...
}
```

or if you want to access it inside the `LogOn.cshtml` view:

```
<div>@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</div>
```

Another possibility is to pass the message as a query string parameter instead of using TempData:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var values = new RouteValueDictionary(new
    {
        controller = "User",
        action = "LogOn",
        errormessage = "You are not authroize to perform this action.Please Login through different account"
    });
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(values);
}
```

and then you could have the `LogOn` action take the error message as action parameter:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string errorMessage)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. i am receiving null in both action and view?

Comment: Are you using TempData or query string parameter?

Comment: in both solutions i receive null in action

Comment: Can you see the query string parameter when being redirected to the LogOn action: `/user/logon?errormessage=....`? I have tested this code and it worked perfectly fine for me in both cases.

Comment: My mistake when i redirect on LogOn page in AuthorizeCore method it return null. its works after removing it as you mention in your updated solution. THANKS

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as answer by clicking on the tick next to it if it helped you solve the problem you were having: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/130891